# Magento 1.8.1 - block type="catalog/product_list" not displaying on the product page

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I'm having a problem with the product page on a Magento site I'm working on.

I'm using the following code in a static block to display products in the header section:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/custom_list.phtml"}}
```

The thing is, the block is displaying fine on all pages except on the "product" page. Am I missing something here?

Hope you guys can help me.

**custom_list.phtml**:

```
<?php
    $_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
    <p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="cat-product-list">
        <ul class="products-grid">
            <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
                <li class="item">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(90,60)->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(TRUE); ?>" width="90" height="60" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: "Am I missing something here?" — Maybe, but not as much as we are.  How are you adding this to the product page?

Comment: Like so: <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('catProducts')->toHtml(); ?> in the header area.

Comment: So is the static block not displaying?  Or is it displaying and your `catalog/product_list` isn't displaying inside the block.

Comment: The catalog/product_list is not displaying inside the block. It is showing up fine on all the other pages except the product view page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the products won't show up on the product page unless the category (`category_id="4"`) is the same as the category of the product you are viewing. Found that
in `List.php`.

```
if (Mage::registry('product')) {
                $categories = Mage::registry('product')->getCategoryCollection()
                    ->setPage(1, 1)
                    ->load();
                if ($categories->count()) {
                    $this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator()));
                }
            }
```

I've added a local copy of the `List.php` file and modified it to my needs. 
It is working fine now.

Comment: Would you please elaborate on how you modified a local copy of `List.php`? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/custom_list.phtml"}}
```

It appears you're using a non-stock template file to render the block. (`catalog/product/custom_list.phtml`).  If I was debugging this problem myself I'd start by looking at the logic inside that template and figuring out why it wasn't displaying a collection on the product page.

Comment: `custom_list.phtml` is just a copy of `list.phtml` in which I've removed some parts of the code (name, price, ratings). I also tried `template="catalog/product/list.phtml"` but the problem is still the same. :(

Comment: I've edited the question to add the code for custom_list.phtml.